# How to get date of closest candidate days and next on each button click continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the date of closest Wednesday or/then Saturday based on given date on button click continuously. How can I achieve this?

```js
$(".btn-info").on("click", function(){
   GetDate('2019-09-10');
});

function GetDate(x){
  x = new Date();
  var cc = x.setDate(x.getDate() + (1 + 5 - x.getDay()) % 7);
  console.log(cc);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Get Next Wednesday / Saturday Date ++ </button>
```

Comment: Kindly approve the answer you found helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. In your function getDate you are resetting the passed argument to todays date.
2. You need to find out the current day and calculate how many days you need to add to get next wed / sat.
3. You need to set the date by adding the calculated days.

Here is what should do:

```js
$(".btn-info").on("click", function(){
   GetDate('2019-09-10'); // Next should be wed 9-11
   GetDate('2019-09-12'); // Next should be sat 9-14
});

function GetDate(x){
  x = new Date(x);
  // Current day can be from 0 (sunday) to 6 (Saturday);
  var currentDay = x.getDay();
  var newDay = currentDay < 3 ? 3 : 6;
  var daysToAdd = newDay - currentDay;

  var cc = x.setDate(x.getDate() + daysToAdd);
  console.log(new Date(cc), new Date(cc).getDay());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Get Next Wednesday / Saturday Date ++ </button>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Void but this is always returning same two dates. First of all I need to get First Wednesday or Sataurday not both of them the other thing is this is not going to next weeks and keep returning same and same data

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".btn-info").on("click", function(){
   var date = getNextWednesday('2019-09-10');
   console.log(date)
});

function getNextWednesday(date){
  let x = new Date(date);
  x.setDate(x.getDate() + (3 + 7 - x.getDay()) % 7);
  return x;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Get Next Wednesday </button>
```

Comment: In general, code-only answers are discouraged. It is ideal to explain _why_ a specific piece of code is the solution to the stated problem. This helps readers who want to learn from the Q&A at a latest date.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```js
console.log(getNext("2019-09-09"));
console.log(getNext("2019-09-10"));
console.log(getNext("2019-09-11"));
console.log(getNext("2019-09-12"));
console.log(getNext("2019-03-06"));

function getNext(dateStr) {
  const date = new Date(dateStr);
  const day = date.getDay();
  const togo = day <= 3 ? 3 - day : 6 - day;
  date.setDate(date.getDate() + togo);
  return date;
}
```